# Geometrically, partitioning the non-zero points in a complex plane with a left coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

I have the group $\mathbb C^*$, which is the group of non zero-complex numbers under multiplication. $H$ is a subgroup of it, where $H = \{a+bi \ |\ a^2 + b^2 = 1\}$.

> The left cosets of $H$ partition the non-zero points in the complex plane. Write a short description of how, and explain what a general coset $(c+di)H$ looks like.

---

The question only only asks for a short answer, so I'm assuming the answer is simple.

What I get is that the $a+bi$ indicate the complex plane, and $a^2+b^2 = 1$ means it will be a circle with diameter 2.

[image: The condition of the subgroup]

---

Any ideas on how to explain how it is partitioned?

Comment: Any ideas on what the cosets $(c + di)H$ look like? That should really have come first in the problem statement in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur No, but there are followup questions "Are the left cosets 5iH and (2-i) equal?" and "Is the element 3-4i in the left coset of 5iH or 7H?"

Comment: Hint: First try to describe a coset of the form $aH$ for a real number $a$. Remember the general fact if $z\in aH$ then $zH=aH$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Thanks for the hint, but I'm afraid I don't really get it :(
Couldn't $a$ be any real number?

Comment: Why don;t you trry with a few easy real numbers first and see what subset of complex plane are obtained?

Comment: Further hint: Multiply by the number 25 get the coset, see what complex numbers are obtained.

Comment: @PVanchinathan If $x$ is the left coset, $x=1$ would give you $a=1$ and $b=0$. Then trying $x$=2, that would just return to $x=1$. Does this mean that you can have left cosets without complex numbers?
As for your further hint, that gives $25h$, but I dont get how you get complex variables from that?

Comment: I think, before launching onto coset, you should  first write some 4  or 5 points lying on the first quadrant of this  circle. There are infinitely many (a,b)  satisfying $a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Oh, so experiment with positive reals where a, b < 1. With a = 0.8 and b = 0.6 for example. So it's basically only on the line of the graph that works. Multiplying it by 25 returns us to any number beforehand. We can only use reals such that $r/(c+di) = a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

Am I on the right track? Thank you for following up with me, I honestly do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : first, notice that $H$ is simply the unit circle : $H = S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb C\mid |z|= 1\}$.

Notice then that given $z,w \in \mathbb C^*$, $w \in zH$ if and only if $\frac{w}{z} \in H$. This observation gives you a way of computing the left coset $zH$.